# Remember folder when browsing file

Tags: files, folder

For uploading a file to the internet, I browse the folder to find a file. How to set ubuntu to remember the last folder browsed instead of opening the default home folder when trying to upload another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible, but I will give you two tips that can help you:

1. Bookmark your most important directories in Nautilus: if you often access a specific folder for uploading files, bookmark it! Open the directory in Nautilus and use the CTRL+D keys to bookmark it... Thus, every time you open the "select file dialog" you can click in the bookmark dir to move directly to the directory!
2. You can copy the path of the file and/or the path to the directory e CTRL+V in the "select file dialog" (in Nautilus you can use the CTRL+L to open the location bar, CTRL+C to copy and use ESC to disable it).

I hope this can help you.

Regards,

Rafael.